# Can I use Smooch.io for different NLP than it provide?

Tags: android, ios, chatbot, smooch, sap-conversational-ai

So I have built my chatbot with **Recast.ai** which provide different channels to integrate to like a telegram, facebook, etc. Now I want to build the same chatbot with the native iOS and Android platforms. So can use the **recast.ai's NLP for integrating smooch's native SDKs** for building a native app? 
Though I  already know that I can use Meya.ai and other chatbot platforms which are listed on smooch's list. But for the time being, I want to build it with the recast.ai. Is there any way of using smooch with recast's NLP?

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by adding Smooch as a channel for Recast.ai.

Here's the Recast.ai tutorial for adding a new channel https://recast.ai/blog/new-channel-bc/.

Smooch provides webhooks for new messages and other events you might want your bot to handle https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks, and endpoints for sending messages from your Recast.ai bot back to the user https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#post-message.

Comment: There's an unofficial tutorial out there for getting started with the Smooch API too https://smooch-walk.herokuapp.com.